# Are gloves of Enlarge Weapon what I want?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

Are gloves of *Enlarge Weapon* (Complete Scoundrel p97) for my half-giant possible and legal by RAW?

With powerful build I already have a large weapon, and I'm looking to get huge sized weapon damage. **I want to stay away from sizing** or other similar weapon enhancements because the penalties aren't worth it to me, as I'd have to waste a feat or get strongarm bracers on top.

I must also mention my DM said I'd have to find a blacksmith who actually can make huge sized weapons, which can be very limiting... with this item basically all weapons I wield would always be one size larger, which could arguably be game-breaking although I'd say my damage is more based on power attack anyway...but extra dice are always welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A use-activated or continuous version of *enlarge weapon* on an item would cost, according to the guidelines, 48,000 gp. The largest possible gain for going from a large weapon to a huge weapon is for a bastard sword or similar, which goes from 2d8 to 3d8, a gain of +1d8, or on average +4½. For the overwhelming majority of weapons, it is a gain of a +1d6, or on average +3½.

You can gain far more than 3-5 damage for 48k gp. Even simply adding *corrosive flaming frost shocking* to a *+1* weapon (costing the same 48k gp) would add +4d6, for an average of +14.
Roughly four times the damage, and just throwing energy properties on a weapon isn't exactly optimal.

So no, I do not think your proposed *gloves of enlarge weapon* are a good solution here at all. Size increases are very slow to increase damage, and are rarely the best way to do so.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but i was under the impression it would be much cheaper (2 spell level x 4 caster level x 2000 continuous for 16k, even less with command word/uses a day) allowing me to then add enhancements to increase the damage even more

Comment: @Smitty See the footnote: spells with durations measured in rounds have their cost multiplied by 4. Command word or other options are bad because you would have to waste combat actions activating it.

Comment: The enlarge isn't quite as bad as you say. The flaming etc will do good damage against something with no defenses, but against something with damage reduction, elemental resistances/immunitites/actually get healed instead, you'll do a lot more damage with the bigger weapon.

Also, weapon size damage gets increased by crits, which is important to keep in mind.

And while it is cheaper for a +1 flaming than the gloves, it becomes more expensive to continue to upgrade the weapon.

Of course, the downside of using up your glove slot is very significant.

Comment: @Scott A larger weapon deals one type of damage, which means it can be shut down. Having four different energy types, plus your physical type, means almost *nothing* is going to be resisting everything. Moreover, adding a +1-equivalent property doesn't cost 48k gp until you adding the 10th property; pre-Epic, the gloves will **never** be the cheaper option. Crits happen far too infrequently invest heavily in, or even much consider.