# What is the biggest weapon wieldable with a Goliath + Wield Oversize Weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, optimization, weapons

I was looking at the Goliath race, and noticed the Powerful Build racial trait, which lets me wield a weapon one size category larger without penalty. I also saw the Wield Oversized Weapon feat, which lets me treat a weapon as one size category smaller and lighter than otherwise.

> **Powerful Build**: […] A goliath can use weapons designed for a creature one size larger without penalty. However, his space and reach remain those of a creature of his actual size. The benefits of this racial trait stack with the effects of powers, abilities, and spells that change the subject’s size category.

> **Wield Oversized Weapon**
> You can treat any weapon as if it were one size category smaller than normal and one category "lighter" for the purpose of determining the amount of effort it takes to wield. […]
>
> This feat subsumes the effects of the Monkey Grip feat. The feats' effects do not stack.

Since one affects the weapon, and one affects the character, I think they would stack. So I could use a Huge greatsword basically as a medium two-handed weapon. My DM lets us use epic feats the same as regular ones, so that's not an issue. So, my question is, using these two features, what is the largest possible weapon I can use (The character I was thinking of uses this as the only criteria for a weapon's quality)? Also, how would I go about satisfying the prereqs for Wield Oversized Weapon as quickly as possible?

EDIT: Also, would Gloves of Enlarge Weapon stack with this for a Gargantuan Greatsword?

Comment: Probably not - see http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/25358/do-powerful-build-and-monkey-grip-stack - but it has a lot to do with the specific wording, which you should link in...  "Wield Oversize Weapon" isn't one of the initial epic feats..."

Comment: I know monkey grip doesn't stack with powerful build, because they both let you wield larger weapons. Wield oversize works differently, essentially by reducing the size of the weapon for you

Comment: Would the clause in Wield Oversized Weapon also apply to Powerful Build, though, since it only specifies Monkey Grip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Looks like a Huge weapon works without penalty

Wield Oversize Weapon says you can treat a weapon as one size category smaller than it is. Thus, you can treat a Huge weapon as if it were Large.

Powerful Build says you can wield weapons one size category larger than yourself without penalty. Since a goliath is a Medium creature, that means a goliath may wield Large weapons without penalty.

Since Wield Oversize Weapon lets you treat the Huge weapon as Large, and Powerful Build lets you wield Large weapons without penalty, you may wield a Huge weapon without penalty.

It does appear that by preventing Wield Oversize Weapon from working with Monkey Grip, the authors were trying to prevent exactly this, which could be an argument for an intent that this shouldn’t work. But by the rules-as-written, that applies only to Monkey Grip, not Powerful Build.

Please note that a size category larger weapon tends to deal only ~1 more damage than its smaller counterpart. There are some exceptions, but it still tends to be small amounts of damage. You can often gain more damage more quickly through other uses of feats. Note also that the size of your *weapon* does not affect reach (well, larger weapons don’t; too-small weapons do), so you do not get extended reach this way, either.

As for [*gloves of enlarge weapon*, those are a really poor idea.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46342/4563) If you meant *strongarm bracers*, those explicitly do not stack with Powerful Build.

Answer (score -1):

I can see how the wording could lead to confusion, but Powerful Build, Monkey Grip, Wield Over-sized Weapon all modify the effort (or additional effort) required to use an inappropriately sized weapon, and thus do not stack.

main faq, pp 51

> Do effects that allow you to use larger than normal
>   weapons, such as the Monkey Grip feat or the Powerful
>   Build racial trait, stack with each other?
>
> These effects do not stack with each other. If you have an
>   effect that allows you to use
>   a weapon one size category larger
>   than you and then gain the same benefit from another source,
>   you are still limited to weapons one size category larger than
>   you.

As a side note, Powerful Build is superior to Monkey Grip for a couple of reasons; you still incur the -2 penalty with MG and it does not allow you to wield an inappropriately sized weapon in your off hand.

Some people try to do a dual wield with MG and Over Sized Two Weapon Fighting, which do stack, but they don't quite do what you might think. OTWF gives you the ability to use a one-handed weapon in your off-hand, but neither feat give you the larger sized weapon in the off-hand.

However, with Powerful build and OTWF, you could wield a large, one-handed weapon in your off-hand. Since you

> ... can use weapons designed for a creature one size larger without penalty.

I've also seen people try to combine this with an exotic weapon (dwarven waraxe or bastard sword) but this is also called out in the faq

main faq pp 57

> The bastard sword, lance, and dwarven waraxe are all two-
>   handed weapons that can be used in one hand under the correct
>   circumstances (the bastard sw
>   ord and dwarven waraxe are
>   shown on Table 7–5 as one-handed
>   exotic weapons, but they’re
>   really two-handed weapons). Trea
>   t all three of these weapons
>   as two-handed weapons when de
>   termining who can use them
>   and how. For example, a Small character cannot use a lance or
>   bastard sword made for a Medium creature, even when
>   mounted (in the case of a lance) or when the Small character
>   has the Exotic Weapon Proficie
>   ncy (bastard sword) feat.

Comment: Wield Oversize Weapon is explicitly and distinctly different from Monkey Grip, Powerful Build, or *strongarm bracers*.

Comment: It's not "an effect that allows you to use a weapon one size category larger than you"?

Comment: No! It's an effect that makes all the weapons smaller to you. The difference is subtle, but significant! A Large Weapon would become a medium weapon, for instance.

Comment: If I face East, and you face West and we both head North, are we not going the same direction?

Comment: By that same argument, I could stack full blade, mercurial, heavy blade, and so on, since although they all deal with the size modifier, they approach it in a slightly different manner, thus leading to the issues that arose with 3.0 that was upgraded with stacking rules in 3.5. In the end, regardless of how RAW is interpreted, I would highly recommend preserving game balance by not allowing multiple *whatever to stack up in this manner.

Comment: @Wyrmwood *None of those examples has anything to do with size modifier.* Full blade is just an exotic Medium weapon with large base dice, mercurial isn’t even something you can apply to any weapon you like, and again just deals more damage than it otherwise would, and the heavy status has drawbacks and again, *has nothing to do with size.* Furthermore, you pay exorbitant fees (multiple EWP feats) to get a few extra d6s. It’s not an efficient use of feats, and doesn’t threaten balance.